# How to retrieve the role associated to a workitem?

Tags: genexus

we are trying to generate a report to list an instance's log. We need to retrieve some attributes including the rol associate to the user who perform de action in the specific workitem.

[image: Report required]

The code right now is:

```
If &WorkFlowProcessInstanceId = 70  // Testing instance
            &WorkflowEventHistoryRepositories = &WorkFlowProcessInstance.Workitems
    Endif
    For &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository in &WorkflowEventHistoryRepositories
        &WorkflowEventHistoryId = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.ActivityId
        &WorkflowEventHistoryActivity = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Activity.Name
        &WorkflowEventHistoryUser = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Participant.Name
        &WorkflowEventHistoryCreated = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Created
        &WorkflowEventHistoryEnded = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Ended
        &WorkflowEventHistoryRole = ???
    Endfor
```

&WorkflowEventHistoryRepository: variable type WorkflowWorkitem

GXFlow
Genexus 18 U8
Web .NET

Answer (score 1):

Every &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Participant (Collection (WorkflowRole)) can have more than one role according to the [documentation](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?10268,WorkflowUser%20Data%20Type%20%28X%20Evolution%201%29):

So, in order to obtain the participant Roles:

```
For &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository in &WorkflowEventHistoryRepositories
        &WorkflowEventHistoryId = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.ActivityId
        &WorkflowEventHistoryActivity = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Activity.Name
        &WorkflowEventHistoryUser = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Participant.Name
        &WorkflowEventHistoryCreated = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Created
        &WorkflowEventHistoryEnded = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Ended
        
        For &ParticipantRoles in &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Participant.Roles //&ParticipantRoles type:WorkflowRole - Collection:true
                // Do something with &ParticipantRoles.Id
                // Do something with &ParticipantRoles.Name
        EndFor
        // Do something with &ParticipantRoles

 Endfor
```

You can obtain more information about the WorkFlowRole datatype [here](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/wiki?17230,WorkflowRole%20Data%20Type).

Comment: I have tested the code with &ParticipantRoles type: WorkflowRole - Collection:false because that is the only way it shows me the id and Name properties. However, it doesn't show any data. The property Count = 0    
&WorkflowParticipantRoles = &WorkflowEventHistoryRepository.Participant.Roles    
&ConteoDeColeccion = &WorkflowParticipantRoles.Count